# TypeError: expected a character buffer object in Python

Tags: python, file, buffer, typeerror

I don't know why I can't write this `document` to file:

```
document=['', 'feeling frisky cool cat hits join us', 'askjoe app add music videos free today saintkittsandnevis', 'give dog flea bath midnight greeeeat smells like dawn', 'cat finds flash drive spent weeks looking', 'downside cat dude means can recognize nice smell pee second', 'louis pine apple make life brighter like star please follow me', 'gonna need nice cup coffee morning', 'gonna need nice cup coffee morning', 'iphone gives warning dies smh']
```

Here's the code for writing into the file:

```
with open("cleaned_tweet.txt", "w") as cleaned_tweet_file:
    cleaned_tweet_file.write(document)
```

Here's the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 85, in <module>
    cleaned_tweet_file.write(document)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the solution, add `str`:

```
with open("cleaned_tweet.txt", "w") as cleaned_tweet_file:
    cleaned_tweet_file.write(str(document))
```

Comment: There were a few comments in IRC after I showed them this solution that this might cause further problems. So if you have a better solution please provide it, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The method [**`write()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.write) takes as an argument a `str` and not a `list` object. This is the cause of your [**`TypeError`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.TypeError) and wraping it in a `str()` call simply *gives you the string representation of the* `list` object `documents` and *not the documents in the list* per se.

By using:

```
with open("cleaned_tweet.txt", "w") as cleaned_tweet_file:
    cleaned_tweet_file.write(str(document))
```

You'll get the `list` object written as a string to your file, so a big string of:

```
"['', 'feeling frisky cool cat hits join us', 'askjoe app add music videos free today saintkittsandnevis', 'give dog flea bath midnight greeeeat smells like dawn', 'cat finds flash drive spent weeks looking', 'downside cat dude means can recognize nice smell pee second', 'louis pine apple make life brighter like star please follow me', 'gonna need nice cup coffee morning', 'gonna need nice cup coffee morning', 'iphone gives warning dies smh']"
```

will be present. Logically not what you're after.

---

Instead of going through the manual (and possibly erroneous) conversion of `list` to `str` you can either use [**`file.writelines()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.writelines) which works with a `list` of strings, or `file.write()` in conjunction with a `for` loop:

With `writelines()`:

```
with open("cleaned_tweet.txt", "w") as cleaned_tweet_file:
    cleaned_tweet_file.writelines(document)
```

No need for a loop or manual conversion here.

With `write` and a simple `for` loop:

```
with open("cleaned_tweet.txt", "w") as cleaned_tweet_file:
    for tweet in document:
        cleaned_tweet_file.write(tweet)
```

This has the same exact effect. It's main advantage is that it allows you to specify additional content per line basis; if you need to add a newline per tweet and a prefix, you add it explicitly `cleaned_tweet_file.write("Tweet: " + tweet + "\n")`.

Comment: so is using str better or a for loop as shown by you?

Comment: Using `write(str(documents))` will write the whole list including brackets `[]` to the file. I don't think you want that. I would suggest `writelines` in this case unless you need each item in your list `documents` on a new line for which I would suggest using the `for` loop with the command `cleaned_tweet_file.write(tweet + "\n")`.

Comment: You're welcome Mona, take a look at the urls I added from the documentation. They're really helpful in understanding these calls.